# Variance of sampling distribution

Tags: probability, statistical-significance, descriptive-statistics

$\operatorname{Var}(\bar X)=\sigma^2/n$ is the formula of variance. I want to check my understanding of this concept. Suppose I want to compute the mean household income of a given city. I collect all possible sample of size $n=30$ (say I pick $30$ households in each suburb) and then compute the mean of each sample. ($\bar x_k$). Then I compute the Mean of these sample mean values: $E(\bar X)=\mu$ which I know will be close to the population mean. Now I want to compute the variance. My question here is that am I computing the variance within each sample or between samples? The $\bar x$ is a mean of a sample and $E(\bar X)$ is the expected value (mean) of the sample means. Which one is the variance. I believe it is the variance within each sample not between the samples?

Comment: For the formula $\sigma^2/n$ to hold you need to sample from the whole population. Equivalently you can assume there is no difference between suburbs. Then $\sigma^2/n$ is the variance *between* the means of the samples. When you calculate variance *within* each sample, you estimate $\sigma^2$, not $\sigma^2/n$.

Answer (score 2):

You have a distribution which you are sampling from, with expectation $\mathbb E[X_i]=\mu$ and variance $\textrm{Var}(X_i)=\sigma^2$, though you do not know these values.

You sample independently $n$ times, and use the sample mean $\bar X = \frac1n \sum X_i$ as your sample estimator of the original mean $\mu$, and you have $\mathbb E[\bar X]=\mu$ and $\textrm{Var}(\bar X)=\frac{\sigma^2}{n}$ (the square-root of this is the "standard error of the mean").

But you still do not know $\sigma^2$ and so do not know $\frac{\sigma^2}{n}$.

One way of estimating it is to use $S^2= \frac1{n-1}\sum (X_i-\bar X)^2$ as your sample estimator of the original variance $\sigma^2$, and you have $\mathbb E[S^2]=\sigma^2$.

So $\frac{S^2}{n}$ is an estimator of the variance of the sample mean and its square-root  $\sqrt{\frac{S^2}{n}} = \sqrt{\frac{\sum (X_i-\bar X)^2}{n(n-1)}}$ is an estimator of the standard error of the sample mean.

Comment: So the $Var(\bar X)$ is the variance of sample mean between the samples? But if I want to compute the variance within each sample then I can use $S^2 = \frac {1} {n-1} \Sigma(X_i - \bar X)^2$.

Comment: @ask9 That depends on what you are interested in.  You say "Now I want to compute the variance" and "My question here is that am I computing the variance within each sample or between samples?" But it for you to say what precisely is that you want the variance of.  My answer explains the $\operatorname{Var}(\bar X)=\sigma^2/n$ that you started with and how to calculate it, but I cannot tell you what you want to measure.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are getting confused about the variance of an individual and the variance of a group. consider a student's exam scores have variance $\sigma^2$. The mean score in a class of 30, will have lower variance than the variance of a single individual, in fact $\sigma^2/30$.

In other words, although the range of student scores will be pretty high, the variability across classes (mean) scores will be much lower, as high scores for 1 student will cancel out low scores for another student in the class.

This cancelling out means that the mean score for any number of students will vary less than the score across individual students

Answer (score 0):

A random variable that takes one of the values $1,2,3,$ each with probability $1/3,$ has variance $\sigma^2=2/3.$

There are $27$ possible samples of size $3,$ each with a sample mean that is at least $1$ but not more than $3.$
$$
\begin{array}{lll}
\text{sample} & \quad & \text{sample mean} \\
1,1,1 & & 1 \\
1,1,2 & & 1+\tfrac13 \\
1,1,3 & & 1+\tfrac23 \\
1,2,1 & & 1+\tfrac13 \\
1,2,2 & & 1+\tfrac23 \\
1,2,3 & & 2 \\
1,3,1 & & 1+\tfrac23 \\
1,3,2 & & 2 \\
1,3,3 & & 2+\tfrac13 \\
2,1,1 & & 1+\tfrac13 \\
2,1,2 & & 1+\tfrac23 \\
2,1,3 & & 2 \\
2,2,1 & & 1+\tfrac23 \\
2,2,2 & & 2 \\
2,2,3 & & 2+\tfrac13 \\
2,3,1 & & 2 \\
2,3,2 & & 2+\tfrac13 \\
2,3,3 & & 2+\tfrac23 \\
3,1,1 & & 1+\tfrac23 \\
3,1,2 & & 2 \\
3,1,3 & & 2+\tfrac13 \\
3,2,1 & & 2 \\
3,2,2 & & 2+\tfrac13 \\
3,2,3 & & 2+\tfrac23 \\
3,3,1 & & 2+\tfrac13 \\
3,3,2 & & 2+\tfrac23 \\
3,3,3 & & 3
\end{array}
$$
The variance of the random variable that takes each of the values in the right column of this array with probability $1/27$ has variance $(2/3)/3 = \sigma^2/n.$

If a coin is toss, the number of "heads" that appear is $0$ or $1,$ each with probability $1/2.$ The variance of that population is $\sigma^2=1/4.$ Now imagine tossing the coin four times. There are $16$ possible outcomes:
$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
\text{sample} & \quad & \text{sample mean} \\
0,0,0,0 & & 0 \\
0,0,0,1 & & 1/4 \\
0,0,1,0 & & 1/4 \\
0,1,0,0 & & 1/4 \\
1,0,0,0 & & 1/4 \\
0,0,1,1 & & 1/2 \\
0,1,0,1 & & 1/2 \\
1,0,0,1 & & 1/2 \\
0,1,1,0 & & 1/2 \\
1,0,1,0 & & 1/2 \\
1,1,0,0 & & 1/2 \\
0,1,1,1 & & 3/4 \\
1,0,1,1 & & 3/4 \\
1,1,0,1 & & 3/4 \\
1,1,1,0 & & 3/4 \\
1,1,1,1 & & 1
\end{array}
$$
The variance of the random variable that takes each of the values in the right column of this array with probability $1/16$ has variance $(1/4)/4 = \sigma^2/n.$

Comment: If I have multiple samples and I want to compute the $E(\bar X)$ then I need to compute the sample mean for each of the samples and then take the average of all these samples means. (this will be close to the population mean ($\mu$). If I want to compute the $Var(\bar X)$ then I need to compute the variance between the sample means using the formula $Var(\bar X) = \frac {\sigma ^2} {n}$?

Comment: @ask9 : $\operatorname E(\,\overline X\,)$ is the same as $\operatorname E(X_1),$ the population mean. Affirmative to your last question.